# Complex integration on a square

Tags: complex-numbers

Integrate $e^{\pi(x+iy)}$ over $C$, where $C$ is the square with vertices $0,1,i,1+i$ traversed once in the counterclockwise direction.

I am learning this on my own and this confused me. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at all four components. For example, going up along $x = 1$, we have $\int_{0}^{i} \text{exp}(\pi(1+iy))\; dy = \frac{\text{exp}(\pi(1+iy))}{\pi\cdot i} = \frac{\text{exp}(0)-\text{exp}(\pi)}{\pi\cdot i} = i\cdot \frac{\text{exp}(\pi)-1}{\pi}$. This is nothing more than 4 line integrals over a 2-dimensional plane.

The complete solution should be: $\int_{0}^{1}\text{exp}(\pi x)\; dx + \int_{0}^{i}\text{exp}(\pi (1+yi))\; dy +\int_{1}^{0}\text{exp}(\pi (x - 1))\; dx + \int_{i}^{0}\text{exp}(\pi (yi))\; dy$.